# Cannot properly close the text file

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have this code that copies an array elements into a text file, and after copying the files I have a button which opens the file i-copied.

```
try 
    {           
        print = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Jofrank\\workspace\\Java\\src\\payroll\\report.txt");
        print.println("EMPLOYEES PAYROLL RECORD AS OF "+dateFormat.format(date));
        print.println();

        for(int x=0;x<department.length;x++)
        {
            print.println("DEPARTMENT: "+department[x].toUpperCase());
            print.println("\tPAYROLL PERIOD\tEMPLOYEE NUMBER\tNAME\tPAY RATE\tHOURS WORKED\tSALARY");
            print.println();

            for(int y=0;y<trans.length;y++)
            {
                if(trans[y] == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if(trans[y].getDepartment().equals(department[x]))
                {
                    print.println("\t"+trans[y].getPayrollPeriod()+"\t"+trans[y].getEmpNo()+"\t\t"+trans[y].getName()+"\t"+trans[y].getPayRate()+"\t\t"+trans[y].getHoursWorked()+"\t\t"+String.format("%,.2f", (trans[y].getPayRate()*trans[y].getHoursWorked())));
                    total+=(trans[y].getPayRate()*trans[y].getHoursWorked());
                }
            }
            print.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTOTAL:\t"+String.format("%,.2f", total));
            print.println();
            total=0;
        }

        print.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Unfortunately, My text file was not UPDATED unless i-close the system.

Is there a way that my text file will be updated automatically without CLOSING the system?

Comment: `flush()` `flush()`. I don't think a `PrintWriter` flushes automatically. A `BufferedWriter` should after X amount of bytes have been written.

Comment: `close()` should, I think, `flush()`.

Comment: You can flush(). close() auto flushes.  Why do you not want to close the writer though?  You should close the writer once you are done with it.

Comment: Most [PrintWriter constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) have autoflush off.

Comment: I closed the writer using `print.close()` right?
I used `flush()` but it is still not working...

Comment: You did `print.flush(); print.close();` ? That should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually create a [**`PrintWriter with autoFlush turned on`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29):

```
print = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream
   ("C:\\Users\\Jofrank\\workspace\\Java\\src\\payroll\\report.txt"), true);
```

Here 2nd parameter is `true`. As per Javadoc:

> `autoFlush - A boolean; if true, the println, printf, or format
>   methods will flush the output buffer`

Comment: The only constructors with the `boolean` for autoflush are with a `Writer` or `OutputStream` class, none with a `String`

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau: Thanks, that was silly copy/paste error. I corrected it.

Comment: isn't this then very similar to a `BufferedWriter` ?

Comment: @SnakeDoc: Loosely it is but `BufferedWriter` doesn't provide `println` etc methods.

Answer (score 0):

That depens much on the system.
flush() usually should work, but this is all not garuanteed.
There are some embedded flash file system where you might call sync, too.

But for the first apporach try `flush()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to empty your stream for it to be written to the file. As others have suggested, use `.flush()` to accomplish this without having to `.close()` your stream. Otherwise I believe `.close()` automagically calls `.flush()` for you to ensure your stream has been emptied and it's contents written to disk or wherever you are directing it.

Answer (score 0):

In documentation it is said that PrintWriter does not flush lines automatically.

You may need to use different constructor for PrintWriter:

```
PrintWriter(File file)
```

but you have to open the file itself and then close it after writing is done.